# How do I save incremented Numbers and calculate them?

Tags: python, while-loop, sum, append, calculation

I want to write myself a program where a variable is going to increment everytime in the while-loop and want at the end, that all values will be stored in a list. At the end the values of the list should be summed with sum().

My problem is that when I execute my program it just let me show the last number of all. I want to have like `l = [5,10,15,...,175]` and not just `l = [175]` (I hope its clear what I mean)

```
def calc_cost():
    x = 0
    k = 34
    j = 0

    while x <= k:
        x = x + 1
        j = j + 5

        l = []
        l.append(j)
        
    print(sum(l))

print(calc_cost())
```

Comment: You are initializing the list `l` in the loop.  Move your `l = []` before the while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def calc_cost():
    x = 0
    k = 34
    j = 0

    l = []

    while x <= k:
        x = x + 1
        j = j + 5

        l.append(j)
        
    print(l)
    return sum(l)
    

print(calc_cost())
```

I made the edit I suggested.  I also returned the sum so it could be printed by the line: `print(calc_cost())`

Here is the output:

```
[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100, 105, 110, 115, 120, 125, 130, 135, 140, 145, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175]
3150
```

Here's a similar approach using the range function:

```
def calc_cost():
    k = 34
    l = list( range( 5, (k+2) * 5, 5 ) )
    print(l)
    return sum(l)


print(calc_cost())
```